# custom Query with thumbnail in wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress

i created a custom query to generate the 3 most recents posts with thumbnail in sidebar. the query works, but seems like the thumbnail parameter in this function not working to show the image in proper size: `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' =>'img-fluid'));?>` but the others parameters( like full, medium etc) worked. i used bootstrap 4 with the last build wordpress version . any suggestion would be welcome. here is my code:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <?php
            $recents_post_sidebar = New wp_query(array(
              posts_per_page => 3

            ));


            if ( $recents_post_sidebar -> have_posts()){

              while (  $recents_post_sidebar -> have_posts()) {
                  $recents_post_sidebar -> the_post(); ?>
                <div class="sidebarpost">
                  <div class="media">
                      <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' =>'img-fluid'));?>" alt="image">
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="mt-0"><?php the_title();?></h5>
                        <p><?php  echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 8);?></p>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <?php  }
            }

            ?>

          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to get the image using get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

[codex reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

```
<img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'post-thumbnail');?>" class="img-fluid" alt="image">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's not working properly : i mean i want an image thumbnail size :120*120 or 150*150; it takes a  wider space which i don't want. or if i can get a rezise image to make it appears the way it should be as a thumbnail.

Comment: Try to add a new image size in your functions.php -> add_image_size( 'thumb-sidebar', 120, 120, true );  Install regenerate thumbnails plugin, scan e rebuild your thumbnails and use your new image size in  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'thumb-sidebar');?>

Comment: i really thank you for  effort. but i prefer the first answer and i'll look for  some solutions to change it via functions.php  or some css class without a plugin. you know the  theme should be capable to work well before installing any plugin. but your answers were very helpful.

Comment: The plugin I suggested you use is also used while you are developing a theme. If you want to try adding a new image size in functions.php you need your old thumbnails to be regenerated for the newly added format. In your case I do not understand why the image size does not work by default 'thumbnail' but I suggested you create a new one with custom dimensions to solve the problem. You can always uninstall the plugin after regenerating the images you need. Anyway ... follow your intuition if you think it's better.